# Installing VMWare ESXi onto Dell PowerEdge 1950

Tags: vmware-esxi, installation

Yesterday I bought a used Dell PowerEdge 1950 server and I am trying to install Esxi 5.5 onto it. I downloaded the ISO file onto a bootable USB. I plug the USB into the front USB drive, but when I start the server, it goes through the BIOS load screen, and then it immediately goes into Windows Server 2008 r2 without giving me a chance to download VMWare. I cannot log into Windows Server 2008 b/c I do not have the admin password. Any advice on what I am doing wrong? Thanks for any help you can give me!
-Patrick

Comment: Burn the iso on a dvd ? else you need to make a bootable USB key

Comment: Hey yagmoth555, I will try to burn it onto a cd now and see if that works.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much for you help! How can I make your reply the "answer"?

Comment: my pleasure, will rewrite it as a answer :) you will be able to mark it answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Burn the iso content on a dvd, or else you will need to make the USB key bootable.